# Problems while creating fonts for different scripts

Tags: fonts, typography

This is for a research purpose.

I was wondering whether the designers face any problems while designing the fonts for different scripts. It is because the alignment and spacing of different scripts are not quite alike, for example, Devanagari and Roman/Latin.

Comment: Are you seeking to make 1 font file to encompass different languages? I don't think that's the standard. Each font is designed for use with a specific alphabet. If the alphabet changes, then the font must change.

Comment: Relevant-https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/creating-a-font-for-a-new-language